# How to do a postback when using modal in a link

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a postback when clicking on a link that opens a popup window modal. I have tried `__doPostBack()` with no luck. Once I remove the two attributes `data-target="#Modal" data-toggle="modal"` PostBack works but my popup window will not work of course.

```
<a href="#" id="OpenNotes" border="0" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NotesModal" alt="Notes" title="Notes">link</a>
```

How can I keep my modal and do a postback when opening it? 
Please help this newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use an event when your modal is opened, like this:

```
$('#NotesModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the attributes **data-target="#Modal" data-toggle="modal"** your anchor will not show anymore the modal. And this is normal.

In this case you can add a click event listener to your anchor so that after dopostback you can show your modal with:

```
$('#OpenNotes').on('click', function(e) {
    do your postback....
    $("#Modal").modal('show');
});
```

For details see the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods)